# How to put several repositories under one domain?

Tags: github-pages

I have two repositories under a free organisation on github: `my_organisation/first` and `my_organisation/second`.

And I want to do the magic the way the first repository is available on `my_organisation.github.io/first` and the second is available on `my_organisation.github.io/second`.

Is it possible? If so, then how can I do it?

Comment: you are talking about gh-pages right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and if you have gh-pages enabled it will happen by default. If not Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Go to the Settings tab of each repository on GitHub and scroll down to the "GitHub Pages" section, might also be available on the left sidebar as "Pages"
2. Under the "Source" section, select the branch as the source for your GitHub Pages site.
3. Save your changes.
4. Wait a few minutes for GitHub to build your site.
   Your repositories should now be available at the following URLs:
   my_organisation.github.io/first
   my_organisation.github.io/second

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works automatically. Example: my repo zeelib has its gh-pages at zacanger.github.io/zeelib, and my other repo niddesa is at zacanger.github.io/niddesa. You don't need to do anything extra to make this work, assuming you have Github Pages enabled on the relevant repos.